# Laravel 4 Form Post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im currently in the process of learning Laravel 4.

I'm trying to create a really simple post form, here is my code for the opening of the form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('post' => 'NewQuoteController@quote')) }}
```

And then within my NewQuoteController i have the following:

```
public function quote() {

   $name = Input::post('ent_mileage');
   return $name;

}
```

I keep getting the following error:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

It's probably something really stupid... Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I have in my routes.php

```
Route::get('/newquote','NewQuoteController@vehicledetails');

Route::post('/newquote/quote', 'NewQuoteController@quote');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For POST looks like you need to change it to:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'NewQuoteController@quote')) }}
```

And you need to have a route to your controller action:

```
Route::post('quote', 'NewQuoteController@quote');
```

Default method for `Form::open()` is POST, but if you need to change it to PUT, for example, you will have to

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'PUT', 'action' => 'NewQuoteController@quote')) }}
```

And you'll have to create a new route for it too:

```
Route::put('quote', 'NewQuoteController@quote');
```

You also have to chage

```
$name = Input::post('ent_mileage');
```

to

```
$name = Input::get('ent_mileage');
```

You can use the same url for the different methods and actions:

```
Route::get('/newquote','NewQuoteController@vehicledetails');

Route::post('/newquote', 'NewQuoteController@quote');

Route::put('/newquote', 'NewQuoteController@quoteUpdate');
```

Comment: Still getting the same, I forgot to add i get this message when I submit the form...

Comment: With the route you're also getting this error? Check the HTML generated. Get the <FORM> line and pastebin it, or edit your message.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException is a route not found error. So your open() must be generating a route different from those you have. Could you paste your HTML <FORM> line?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/l4_site/public/newquote/quote" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="ej7Wk63SHHM2OWyzqo6o6dz5E8rI5cBVckZdPjcc">

Comment: PUT? Are you doing POST or PUT?

Comment: Sorry, changed to put and now I'm getting this: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()

Comment: Got it to work without an error but for some reason the input isn't being carried across, I can worry about this now. :-)

Comment: You are using `Input::post()`. It's `Input::get()`.

Comment: If you do `dd(Input::all())` you get nothing?

Comment: got it working now, i had another input with the same name... 1 question - how can i get it to stay in the same URL for instance http://localhost:8888/l4_site/public/newquote/quote instead of http://localhost:8888/l4_site/public/quote

Comment: Edited to try to answer you. I'm not sure I understood your question. :)

Comment: Sorry Antonio, when you click the submit button instead of the URL changing to localhost:8888/l4_site/public/quote in the browser could it not change to localhost:8888/l4_site/public/newquote/quote ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42407/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-scottbaxter)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your form open to

```
{{Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'route' =>'NewQuoteController@quote')}}
```

and in your controller access the form input using one of the Input methods ?

```
public function quote() {

    $name = Input::get('ent_mileage');

    return $name; 
}
```